# How to calculate the derivative of the following function?

Tags: matrix-calculus

How would you go about calculating the derivative d/dx of the below function f(x)?
a and c are scalars.

$f(x)=\phi(x)^T\phi(x)$, $\phi(x)=$$\begin{bmatrix}\sin(ax_1) \\ \sin(acx_2) \\ 2x_1 \\ 2cx_2\end{bmatrix}$

My guess would be the following (i.e. treating each element in the vector as its own function to the power of two, and spreading the derivative on two columns to get a Jacobian), but that's just a wild guess, as I have never worked with equations with such structure before.

$J_f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}a \cdot cos(2ax_1) & 0\\0 & ac \cdot cos(2acx_2)\\8x_1 & 0\\0 & 8c^2x_2\end{bmatrix}$

I usually always had an x vector inside of an equation, not individual elements of the variable vector mixed in one vector... Maybe I can/should somehow rewrite the equation so that there is a variable vector in there?

Comment: The derivative of $f(x) = \|\phi(x)\|^2_2 $ is $Df(x)h = 2 \phi^T(x)D\phi(x)h$.

Comment: And what would () be?

Comment: It is the derivative of $\phi$, so something like $D\phi(x)h = \begin{bmatrix} a \cos ( a x_1)h_1 \\ ac \cos (ac x_2) h_2 \\ 2 h_1 \\ 2 h_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! Would that be the "Chain rule"?

Comment: Yes, it is known as the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scalar function is written as
$f(\mathbf{x})=\| \mathbf{z} \|^2$.
The differential approach yields
$$
df
=2 \mathbf{z}^T d\mathbf{z}
=2 \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{J}d\mathbf{x}
$$
where we have used the Jacobian
matrix $\mathbf{J}$ defined as:
$$
\mathbf{J}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a \cos(ax_1) & 0 \\
0 & ac \cos(acx_2) \\
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2c
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The derivative is thus
$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}
= 2 \mathbf{J}^T \mathbf{z}$
which is 2-by-1.